# Why do forced closed questions retain upvotes?

Tags: discussion

If a question is forced closed, say, because it's a duplicate, why does it retain upvotes?

For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35946839/javascript-and-use-strict-again) was marked as a duplicate and yet at the current moment it has a +3 score.  I'm struggling to see through the dichotomy of an upvoted duplicate question.

Why is it possible?  Or is there a case when a forced closed question is actually a good question?

---

This isn't a duplicate to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318770/should-we-still-allow-upvoting-questions-that-are-have-been-marked-as-duplicates) because the other question pertains to upvoting after a question is closed.  My question is why a question retains its previous upvotes when it's forced closed.  The difference is timing.  At the point in time when it's deemed a question is a duplicate (or whatever), at that moment -- how could it be a good question?

Comment: Nobody has said that a question that turns out to be a duplicate is bad.  Whether it's a duplicate or not has no bearing on whether or not it's a good question.

Comment: What do you mean by "dichotomy"?

Comment: @Will - isn't a requirement of a good question that it isn't a duplicate?  Or vague?  Or any of the other numerous reasons why a question is forced closed?

Comment: @RichN - to explain what I mean by dichotomy:  doesn't the reason why a question is forced closed make it inherently not a good question?  Perhaps Will's response to my last comment will clarify this.

Comment: Votes (or more specifically the reputation points they carry) are removed when the question is *deleted.*  Closure isn't the end of a question's life-cycle; *deletion* is, and even deletion can be reversed.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - so the reason is that the question retains its positive score in the event that it's re-opened?

Comment: @Will - why do people downvote a question when it's vague, or a duplicate, or whatever, if those reasons have no bearing on whether it's a good question?

Comment: The scores are never deleted.

Comment: @Will A post being a duplicate doesn't have *no* bearing on it's quality.  It's if nothing else, at least a possible indication that the question isn't poorly researched.  The question can still be a good question, which is why there are upvoted duplicates, but the fact that the post is a duplicate at least can influence it's quality to *some* degree.

Comment: I'm not sure if OP is being obtuse on purpose because he's pissed about getting a question downvoted and closed as dupe.  Either way, the reasons for downvoting a question are clear and well documented.  They do not include "is a duplicate".  As @Servy said, failing to research *is* a reason, but sometimes duplicates aren't always clear. If you ask a good question and someone discovers that it is an unobvious duplicate of another question, then there is no need to downvote.  If you ask a super awesome question about your NullReferenceException, I'm going to downvote the crap out of it.

Comment: @Will - I don't believe I've ever had a question downvoted or closed as a dupe (well, before this one... which may or may not be downvoted because people think it's a dupe).  I'm not pissed.  I'm curious because it honestly doesn't make sense to me.  And I'm a she, not a he.

Comment: I believe you. It just seemed odd that you're pushing back so hard against the concept of an upvoted closed dupe. And I'm a goat IRL.  A really smart goat.  But I still do eat tin cans, which is kinda dumb, I admit. Baaa.

Comment: @Will I thought goats were polite man..... you disappoint me, you goat-programmer you...

Comment: @Patrice I'm a baaa-stard, I know