# Why do closed, off-topic questions work the way they do?

Tags: discussion, scope

As background, the primary tag that I assist with here (as well as Super User, Ask Ubuntu, and Unix & Linux) is [windows-subsystem-for-linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-subsystem-for-linux) (originally known as "Ubuntu Bash on Windows", which is a bit more descriptive for those that don't know what it is).  This tag gets a lot of off-topic questions (at least here on Stack Overflow).  I also do some [fish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fish), which as a shell tends to get some non-programming questions as well.

*Some* of this has apparently been asked before, but the [original question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318770/should-we-still-allow-upvoting-questions-that-are-have-been-marked-as-duplicates) seems to be deleted.  I only found the link to that question via [Why do forced closed questions retain upvotes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318799/11810933).  And honestly, I can see reasons behind this for most of the "Close" reasons (duplicate, lacks details or clarity, etc.).   But "off-topic" is another story.

And anyway, "upvotes on off-topics" is just a small part of my question here.

From [What is a "closed" or "duplicate" question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10582/902710) (summarized and reformatted to highlight each point):

> When a question is closed:
>
> - no additional answers may be posted to it
> - ... although the question and existing answers can still be edited
> - ... and voted upon
> - ... and will continue to count for badges

And, while not stated there, the question and all answers continue to accrue reputation from upvotes.

Throughout that post, I see the "What?", the "Who?", the "How?", and even the "How many?".  But nowhere in there do I see "Why" this works the way it does.

So *why* ...

1. *Why are upvotes allowed on off-topic questions?*

   Since the [original question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318770/should-we-still-allow-upvoting-questions-that-are-have-been-marked-as-duplicates) and any answers along with it have been deleted, I need to ask this part again.  What is the purpose in an off-topic question being eligible for upvotes?  According to [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), off-topic questions are by definition *not* "well asked":

   > ###### Answer well-asked questions
   >
   > Save yourself some frustration and avoid trying to answer questions which ... are not about programming as defined in the help center.

   So it the question is determined to be off-topic, then it's (per the Help Center), not "well asked", and it shouldn't be upvoted, right?  Or again, *why* is upvoting even enabled for off-topics?

   At present, the highest voted question in the [windows-subsystem-for-linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-subsystem-for-linux) tag is the (IMHO wildly) off-topic [Disable beep in WSL terminal on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36724209/11810933).  A comment on the day this question was originally asked pointed out that it was off-topic, but it took 3 years to get a close-vote to pass (two previous attempts were invalidated, presumably because it's a low-traffic tag).

   Shouldn't we instead be highlighting good, on-topic, programming questions as the highest-voted?

   It's clear that this information was helpful to a number of people, but it would have been just as helpful on Super User, where it belonged in the first place.

   And that's just one example.  Looking at the [highest-voted questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-subsystem-for-linux?tab=Votes) in that tag:

   - Five were closed as off-topic
   - Three more probably should have been (note - I'm not asking for close-votes on these "inactive" questions.  Just highlighting the problem):

     - [How to copy/paste](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38832230/11810933)
     - [A general installation issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44829878/11810933) with 22 different answers (so far)
     - [Moving the root filesystem to another drive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38779801/11810933)
   - Two seem fully on-topic (and should be the ones that are highlighted, IMHO):

     - [matplotlib on WSL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43397162/11810933)
     - [Using WSL as the VSCode terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44450218/11810933)
   - Oddly, one of the ones that was closed *feels* on-topic to me, regarding [creating multiple development environments using different WSL instances](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51584765/11810933).  That's really something that would typically be *best* answered here on SO by programmers.

   As you get into the 11-20 range, things start to look a bit better (but not totally).  The Top 10 likely has more off-topic questions because "general-computing" questions are, by definition, helpful to more people.

   Wouldn't having off-topic questions automatically set to "0 upvotes":

   - Highlight the better questions?
   - Still provide the answers for people searching?  (assuming that's one of the goals here for off-topic questions - see below)

   Side-note:  I see no problem with allowing upvotes on the answers, since (as long as the question is *there*), there needs to be some way to "sort" the answers by "helpfulness", at least.

---

2. *Why do off-topic questions and their answers gain Rep?*

   A.k.a. "Why do we give rep on a programming site for non-programming topics?"

   Upvotes and Rep, however, are (or should be) two totally separate topics.  Even if we do allow upvotes for off-topic questions and answers, should those upvotes result in rep?

   Given the current system, there's almost no downside, and tremendous potential upside to asking and answering off-topic questions.  Taking just the  [top 5 off-topic WSL questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1532891), we can see that (roughly) 13,000 rep has been granted to the askers of these 5 questions.  More astoundingly, nearly 30,000 reputation has been granted to those who provided answers.

   The aforementioned [Disable beep in WSL terminal on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36724209/11810933) has (so far) granted almost **16,000 reputation** to the asker, because it was also self-answered almost immediately after asking.  While I know that there's nothing inherently wrong with posting a question where the answer is already known, the problem here, of course, was that it was grossly off-topic.  But that non-programming question and answer have given one user a number of privileges and responsibilities on Stack Overflow, a (to state the obvious) programming-focused site.

   Perhaps the answer is that the question should have been deleted much earlier, but that's often difficult-to-impossible on lower-traffic tags.  That particular question failed to muster even enough votes-to-close in two previous reviews, let alone getting enough delete-votes.

   But an equally bad issue can be found in the [zsh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zsh) tag, with [How to permanently set $PATH on Linux/Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14637979/11810933).  I'm not too worried about the question-asker, in this case, since there's clearly enough *other* rep in programming-related topics to offset any off-topic rep.  But the top answer there has given over 11k rep (of their 12k).  And here's the kicker -- That answer originally had a fairly significant security issue in leaving a trailing `:` in the path (as noted in the comments).  It was only fixed in an edit by another user some 18 months later.  So here we have granted over 11k rep for an answer in an off-topic question, but one that wasn't even very good in the first place.

   - Should off-topic questions and answers gain rep at all?
   - Or at least stop from the point in time that the question was determined to be off-topic?

---

3. *Why "freeze in place" the answers that are in effect at the time of closing?  Why not allow new answers?*

   Shifting gears a bit, but it seems odd that the "one downside" of a question being closed is that it can't gather new answers.  If a question is closed while it still has no answers, then this is great.  But if there are answers, then:

   - The pool of answers is limited to those that were in place at the (often arbitrary) time that the question gathered enough close-votes.
   - The "fastest gun in the west" problem means that a hastily-written answer may have been the only one that got locked in (assuming the question is closed quickly).
   - Things change (especially when it comes to constantly-updated software like WSL), but those changes can only be noted in the comments (or by editing an existing answer, *if* appropriate).
   - Upvotes (see previous issue) are divided among a smaller pool of answers.  While the answer may be "helpful" (even if off-topic), there may be a *better* or *updated* way of doing something that cannot be shared or voted up.

   I've actually become hesitant to vote-to-close some older off-topic questions now after seeing this problem manifest multiple times.  For example:

   - [How to change default directory in Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59057687/11810933) is a question that I VTC'd as off-topic, and it was subsequently closed.  Through a meta discussion [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/413202/11810933), the question ended up being reopened. Even though it seems most people disagreed with it being reopened, it got the 3 votes needed.

     And you know what?  I ended up being *happy* that the question got reopened, since someone posted a new answer that was the *right* answer, given recent updates in WSL, Windows, and Windows Terminal.
   - There are a few other off-topic questions where I believe there's a better answer, but I'm torn between VTC'ing them since I do believe they are off-topic, or answering them to make sure they have the most up-to-date info.  If the questions are *here* and visible, I'd personally rather be able to provide good answers to them even if I didn't receive any rep
     in return (see #2).

---

4. *Why not `noindex` off-topic questions?*

   The problem with upvotes and rep gains is likely compounded by them being returned in search results in the first place.  Searching Google (signed out, so as to not contaminate results with my past history) for:

   - *turn off beep in wsl*
   - *disable bell in wsl*
   - (and other variants)

   ... returns the closed question here.  But perhaps even more surprisingly, general, non-WSL searches:

   - *disable bell in bash*
   - (and other variants)

   Also return that same question!

   Meanwhile, the equally good questions:

   - [How to disable Bash on Windows notification sound effect](https://superuser.com/q/1108120) on Super User
   - [How to disable system beep for non-privileged user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/2381) (Unix & Linux Stack)
   - [How to turn off the beep only in bash tab-complete](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/73672) (Unix & Linux Stack)

   ... get buried.

   Why not set closed tags to `noindex` so that the on-topic questions and answers on other Stack sites can get the traffic, votes, and rep?

---

5. *Why are off-topic questions not migrated to a more appropriate site more often?*

   I can probably answer this one myself, but I still see it as a bit of a chicken-and-the-egg problem.  I've been told that migrating questions takes deliberate moderator effort, so it should only be done when an off-topic question has answers, and preferably good answers.  And, of course, it needs to be within a relatively short span of time.

   That narrows the list down quite a bit, especially since many questions don't get enough close votes in time to be migrated anyway.

---

6. *Why are off-topic questions not deleted more often and more quickly?*

   Mostly, the same issue as before.  It's often hard enough to get enough close-votes on a question in time, let alone (especially for something like WSL) get enough 10k rep users to delete-vote it.  And, in the meantime, they can clearly gain massive traction.  Close and delete-votes "expire" fairly quickly, but the rep gained from these off-topic questions continues even after they are deleted.

---

7. *Related - Why are off-topic questions with upvoted answers not [Roomba'd](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba)?*

   Auto-delete scripts only clean up questions with no or low-voted answers - Why?  We know that users are likely to upvote even off-topic questions (and especially their answers).  If we want to keep things "on-topic" as much as possible, why not auto-delete off-topic questions after a certain period of time, regardless of votes?

---

Related side-note -- When is (and isn't) WSL (or bash, etc.) "off-topic"?

While I try to "squint" and see the "programming" side of many of these questions, I hope we can agree that the off-topic question, "How do I copy a file from WSL/Linux to Windows?" doesn't magically become on-topic if it changes to, "How do I copy a Python file from WSL/Linux to Windows?".  However, if there was some particular reason that Python files acted *differently* than regular files in this case, then yes, that would likely make it [a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

*Hopefully*, those would be weeded out by a variation on the minimal-viable-example rule.  If the MVE boils down to a "general computing" case (it can be demonstrated without any developer tool or language), then it's usually off-topic.  If the MVE can only be demonstrated in a way that it is "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development", then it's probably on-topic.

That said, it seems to me that even the moderators here struggle with agreeing with "on-topic".  I'd love to understand why:

- One mod considers [Windows 10 Bash (Ubuntu) - How to scroll up?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41774260/11810933) on-topic and specifically reopened it after it was closed (it's now been closed again), but ...
- ... another mod closed [How do you install multiple, separate instances of Ubuntu in WSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51584765/11810933).  Again, that one seems "unique to software development" to me.

Comment: The answer to 6/7 of your questions is simple: Because off-topic questions _can still be useful_.

Comment: @Nick Okay, then why disallow new answers?  That certainly reduces the usefulness while giving no indication that the older answers may be out of date, or that there may be a better answer available.  If off-topic questions are *useful* here, then I'm still struggling with the whole "close for off-topic" system.

Comment: @Nick And that might cover 5 of them (if that), but then we still have the question of providing programming-site-rep on non-programming questions.  That seems to indicate, as well, that we want to *encourage* off-topic questions here.  The current "Off-topic Close" system is a "mixed message", at best.

Comment: Because while we don't want to _generate_ off-topic content, we also don't want to delete _useful_ content. There aren't enough curators to close all off-topic posts before they get useful answers. But if a useful answer has been posted, we then don't want to delete it. Where an off-topic question has already been answered closure is simply to prevent generation of _additional_ off-topic content.

Comment: @Nick Again, things change, and a "useful" answer one day may not be the "best answer" (or even a "good answer") a year later.  It may, in the `zsh` example cited, even be a *bad* answer from day one, but still get upvoted (it was "useful", but a security risk, unbeknownst to the upvoters).

Comment: Then, hopefully, a better answer will be available on a the site the answer is suited to, and that'll get more votes. The fact an **off-topic** question has answers from people that answered (instead of flagging/VTCing) is irrelevant. As for the example, if you know it's vulnerable, downvote it.

Comment: @Larnu While a nice theory, we've demonstrated above that it's unlikely, since off-topic Stack Overflow answers will almost always be indexed higher than the on-topic answers on other sites.  And the "just downvote it" is kind of a ridiculous suggestion when there are over 1000 upvotes ...

Comment: So you want to promote the off-topic and bad answer on [so] more because it *might* get more views? Seems like a terrible idea to me... Might as well combine all the sites and have an "anything goes" community. Sounds like "fun". Wait a minute...

Comment: @Larnu Huh?  One of my questions was why we don't `noindex` the off-topic SO question so that it gets *fewer* views.  What did I say that makes you think I advocate *promoting* bad answers?

Comment: By suggesting that an answer not be posted on a site it is on topic for, @NotTheDr01ds , you are implicitly saying you think they should be here, and thus the bad answer gets more views. You don't fix the problem by getting that answer more views by allowing more answers to an already off topic question

Comment: @Larnu You might want to reread (or read) my question in its entirety.  I'm looking for *more* curation, not less.  I'm looking to have the questions be on the on-topic sites and promote them *there*.  The "allowing additional answers" is just one part (and a bandaid to the other problems I mentioned) -- Deindexing (or deleting in the first place) would get more views on the right sites.

Comment: You're words when I suggested you post the answer on the site that it's ontopic for: *"While a nice theory, we've demonstrated above that it's unlikely"*. You disagreed with the idea...  As you did with downvoting... You're not helping if you do neither of those. End of story. Downvote, it's good for the community. Contrary to minority belief, not enough people do it.

Comment: @Larnu The "nice theory" part is that it will "get more votes" on the proper site.  I *want* it to get more votes (and it sounds like you do as well), but the problem is that if an off-topic question remains here (and indexed), it will bury the on-topic question on, say, Super User.

Comment: @Larnu And I didn't say I don't downvote (I do, and frequently), but you can't reasonably believe that downvoting will offset 1000 upvotes from folks who don't even seem to realize that it's off-topic (or dangerous).

Comment: I agree with the question. Closing a question but continuing to reward its asker and answerers with rep is inconsistent; preventing future answers but hosting the question and its existing answers indefinitely is illogical. Because votes are seen as indicating value, such questions do not get deleted. It does not really make sense, but the mechanics of the site seem to have calcified this way.

Comment: @khelwood as far as I understand [meta-tag:historical-lock] is intended to address most troublesome cases of such questions; it keeps content with hundreds thousands views available for reading but blocks rewards (I randomly clicked one of the examples in this post and it turned out rather strong candidate for h/l)

Comment: @gnat That's the first I've heard of historical-lock.  That's good info that seems to be very relevant here.  Thank you!

Comment: @gnat Turns out these *aren't* candidates for historical-lock.  To be a candidate, it has to *first* be deleted then undeleted, or closed and then reopened.  See my question [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/414994/11810933) and the comments